# Erlang, can't connect two nodes in local host

Tags: erlang

So, I'm on Ubuntu 20 and i'm trying to connect two local nodes.

I tried

```bash
erl -sname user1
```

and

```bash
erl -sname user2
```

With this simple storage server:

```
-module(kvs).
-export([start/0, store/2, lookup/1]).

start() -> register(kvs, spawn(fun() -> loop() end)).
store(Key, Value) -> rpc({store, Key, Value}).

lookup(Key) -> rpc({lookup, Key}).
rpc(Q) ->
  kvs ! {self(), Q},
  receive
     {kvs, Reply} -> Reply
  end.
loop() ->
  receive
   {From, {store, Key, Value}} -> put(Key, {ok, Value}), From ! {kvs, true}, loop();
   {From, {lookup, Key}} -> From ! {kvs, get(Key)}, loop()
  end.
```

If the two nodes are connected I should be able to start it in user1 and use it also in user2, right?

EDIT: If I ping, I see they are connected because it returns pong, but still i can't make them work together on the server written above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're registering the process *locally* and also referring to it *locally*.

You see… [register/2](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang#register-2) gives the process a name that's only known in the same node where the process lives.

So, in your case, if you call `start/0` on `user1@localhost`, to send it a message from `user2@localhost` you can't just use `kvs ! {the, message}`, you need to let Erlang know that the process lives in the other node. To do that, you can use `{kvs, 'user1@localhost'} ! {the, message}` if you know the node in advance… or you will need a different way to register and address your process.

For instance, you can use [global](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/global), [pg](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/pg), or some third-party libraries, like `gproc`.

Comment: Ok thanks, then i really didn' t understand how our professor made this example and connected two node on the same machine simply by doing that. It depends on the version?

Comment: No, it does not depend on the version. Maybe he was using the `rpc` module. So, you spawn the process in a node and then, from the other, you do something like `rpc:call('node1@…', kvs, lookup, [something]).`